# Enquiry about Dimensions

Tags: vocabulary, word-choice

I wanna describe dimensions; would you please let me know which of these below sentences are correct?

1. It is 3cm in length and 1cm in width.
2. It has 3cm of length and 1cm of width.
3. It is 3cm long and 1cm wide.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

These are fine:
    It is 3cm in length and 1cm in width.
   It is  3cm in breadth and 1cm in width and 15 cm in height.
    It is 3cm long and 1cm wide.

**But** "It has 3cm of length and 1cm of width," is wrong: try-
It has a length of 3cm and a width of 1cm.